# Is laminated or triple pane Best choice to replace window pane glass?

Tags: insulation, windows, noise-reduction, window-frame, air-leaks

Our windows (from 2000s) leak air and we can hear street noise in otherwise quiet neighborhood eg car doors, conversations on sidewalk. We use honeycomb cellular shades as dual purpose to also block air. Windows are double pane. I believe replacing only the glass should suffice as frames look good.

Will triple pane only help with leaky air?

Or Is triple pane + laminate the best option for air and noise?

What metrics or data points should I be asking the installers for? STS? R-value?

Related

[What is the difference between double glazing and triple glazing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28308/20755)

[How can I muffle street noise increase from triple-pane windows?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/30653/20755)

Comment: Triple pane needs thicker frames. At least for the quality windows we chose.

Comment: I would be surprised if the energy savings going from double to triple panes would ever come close to covering the cost of replacement.  This may sound strange but if you leave your furnace fan on 24x7, the background fan noise will suppress other sounds.  And your air will be cleaner.

Comment: You should be asking your installer about U values. The lower the U value of a window the better it insulates. This may help: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/179770/109740

Comment: Is there a possibility the windows were originally installed wrong ? How would I check this?